# Zend Framework 2 - Navigation concept

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have used ZF2's Skeleton application for learning. Now, i'm learning Navigation.
I have a problem in that.

1. Added the navigation class in service_manager.

   ```
   'Navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
   ```

   (Modules's config file: module.config.php)
2. Having the following codes in nav_config.php.
       (config/nav_config.php)

   ```
   <?php
   return array(
     'navigation' => array(
       'default' => array(
           'disc' => array(
               'label' => 'Album',
               'route' => 'album',
               'pages' => array(
                   'index' => array(
                       'label' => 'Listing',
                       //'route' => 'album/index',
                       'module' => 'album',
                       'controller' => 'album',
                       'action' => 'index',
                   ),
                   'add' => array(
                       'label' => 'Add Album',
                       //'route' => 'album/add',
                       'module' => 'album',
                       'controller' => 'album',
                       'action' => 'add',
                   ),
               ),
           ),
       ),
     ),
   );
   ```
3. In layout.php, placed this code.

   ```
   <?php
   echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs('navigation')->setMinDepth(0)->setLinkLast(true)->render();
   ?>
   ```

While accessing hostname/disc,  i'm getting "Album" text in breadcrumb.
When i'm accessing hostname/disc/add, again i'm getting the same, that is "Album" alone.
But i would like to get "Album / Add Album". Please guide to achieve.

Comment: For what reason have you commented out the route parameter and used the module/controller/action?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to check the dynamic urls. So i have used module/controller/action. Let me know your suggestion.

Comment: Change to unique route names and use the route parameter in the navigation array. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your 'disc' node to include controller and action and it should work:

```
<?php
return array(
  'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        'disc' => array(
            'label' => 'Album',
            'route' => 'album',
            'controller' => 'album', // add this
            'action' => 'index',     // add this
            'pages' => array(
                'index' => array(
                    'label' => 'Listing',
                    //'route' => 'album/index',
                    'module' => 'album',
                    'controller' => 'album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
                'add' => array(
                    'label' => 'Add Album',
                    //'route' => 'album/add',
                    'module' => 'album',
                    'controller' => 'album',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
```